# Using a switch with a recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, switch-statement

I am creating a program that coverts any base 10 number to any other base up to 36 using recursion and I cannot find the right spot to put my switch for changing any remainder that is returned by the recursive function larger than 9 into its letter counterpart. (A = 10, B = 11...) My conversion function uses recursion and seems to be making it a bit more difficult to implement the switch. Where would be the appropriate place to put the switch?

Converting 200 from decimal to hexadecimal should be c8. My program prints it as 128. The 12 should be c which is what the switch is for.

I am using recursion since it is a pretty simple way to convert to a new base. 
As of now the program runs but still continues to output just numbers and is not switching. Thanks for any replies!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int baseConversion(int num, int base);

int main()
{
    int numInput;
    int baseInput;

    cout << "Enter number for conversion: " << endl;
    cin>>numInput;
    cout<<"Enter the base you would like the number converted to: "<<endl;
    cin>>baseInput;

//int temp2 = baseConversion(numInput,baseInput);


cout << numInput <<" to the base "<<baseInput<<" is: ";
switch(baseConversion(numInput,baseInput))
{
    case 10:
    cout << "A";
    break;
    case 11:
    cout << "B";
    break;
    case 12:
    cout << "C";
    break;
    case 13:
    cout << "D";
    break;
    case 14:
    cout << "E";
    break;
    case 15:
    cout << "F";
    break;
    case 16:
    cout << "G";
    break;
    case 17:
    cout << "H";
    break;
    case 18:
    cout << "I";
    break;
    case 19:
    cout << "J";
    break;
    case 20:
    cout << "K";
    break;
    case 21:
    cout << "L";
    break;
    case 22:
    cout << "M";
    break;
    case 23:
    cout << "N";
    break;
    case 24:
    cout << "O";
    break;
    case 25:
    cout << "P";
    break;
    case 26:
    cout << "Q";
    break;
    case 27:
    cout << "R";
    break;
    case 28:
    cout << "S";
    break;
    case 29:
    cout << "T";
    break;
    case 30:
    cout << "U";
    break;
    case 31:
    cout << "V";
    break;
    case 32:
    cout << "W";
    break;
    case 33:
    cout << "X";
    break;
    case 34:
    cout << "Y";
    break;
    case 35:
    cout << "Z";
    break;
    default:
        cout <<baseConversion(numInput,baseInput);
    }
    cout<<endl;

return 0;
}

int baseConversion(int num, int base)
{
if(num == 0 || base == 10)
    return num;

return (num% base) + 10*baseConversion(num / base, base);

}
```

`

Comment: `'A' + 0..25` is a solution

Comment: I don't see why either `switch`, or recursion is actually necessary to solve this. Also post a complete test case ([MCVE]) please.

Comment: Can you not just index a "0123456789ABCDEF..........." array?

Comment: Your baseConversion method is totally useless for bases greater than 10, so there is no place you could put that `switch` that would do anything toward solving the problem.  Try again with a valid base conversion method.  Hint: that outputs a string, not a number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works for bases greater than 10... Could you explain why you say that?

Comment: I'm quite sure it does not work for bases greater than 10.  Even imagining it might work implies such a fundamental misunderstanding of what a number within a computer is, that there is no easy way to explain it to you.  First you need to unlearn something very wrong, before you can learn anything correct.

Comment: A number in a computer is not a string.  When you multiply a number by ten, you are not shifting a string to the left by one.  Outside a computer, those not comfortable with math might act like a number is a string and might have even been taught that multiplying by 10 shifts that string left one place.  That viewpoint won't serve you very well in math outside a computer, and it is totally wrong for math inside a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude recursive base conversion function to help you understand the difference between that and what you did:

```
std::string baseConversion(int num, int base)
{
   std::string result;
   if (num>=base) result = baseConversion(num/base, base);
   num %= base;
   if (num<10) result += (char)('0' + num); else result += (char)('A'+num-10);
   return result;
}
```

That function starts with an empty string when `num<base` or with a (recursive computation of) all but the rightmost digit when `num>=base`.

Then it appends the last digit to that.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need a switch, as also pointed in the comments : this can be done like so

```
string f(int n, int base) {
    string res = "";
    if (n < base) 
        res += n < 10 ? n : n + 'A' - 10;
    else {
        string t = f(n / base, base); 
        res += t + (n % base) < 10 ? n % base : (n%base) + 'A' - 10; //t should be on LHS
    }
    return res;
}
```

also, take care that you should return appending individual chars into either a string or a char array and not int data type as you are doing.

as again pointed out in comments, don't need recursion here unless just for learning.

Comment: I think the recursion is great for understanding.  Without recursion, you get the digits produced in the opposite sequence from what you want.  With recursion, you can easily use the digits in the sequence you want regardless of whether that is the sequence they would normally be produced in.  There are certainly other ways to deal with the production sequence being backwards, including the trivial inefficient way of letting std::string take care of it, and more difficult efficient ways.  But for understanding base conversion without that worry, recursion is clearer.

Comment: It is the `switch` not the recursion, that is bad for understanding and learning.  Generalizing rules so that multiple cases can be detected and processed without being individually listed is essential to programming.  If you don't do that, you are just writing some bad code but you are not programming.  (Both of us changed the `switch` to something a programmer might reasonably do).

Comment: recursion is a great problem solving tool, agreed; just pointing out here that iteration could do that same without the additional function stacks; and I think here it is more intuitive too (entirely a personal opinion though); switch : couldn't agree more